# I have a dual boot windows 7 and server 2008 laptop which is not letting me load win7

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008, multi-boot

I have installed Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7 on a Sony VAIO VPCEB1E0E laptop, which is only available in the UK.

For some reason it will not let me use the cursors and go into Windows 7 at the operating selection screen.
I can press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to go into Windows Server 2008 but the down cursor doesnt work and I also cannot get into the BIOS to disable dual boot mode.

What can I do?

Comment: Try an external keyboard..... .

Answer (score 0):

Its kind of weird, the typical error is not been able to use the keyb at all. You should try to enable Legacy USB in the Notebook Setup. 
Also the "detect Keby" option if exists.

btw, the dual boot is not in the bios, what you sea is a boot manager that lets you select your OS. This is a piece of software in the boot partition. You can change this from Windows. Execute "msconfig" in a CMD window and select your prefered OS to boot from there. 
You could also use bcdedit, but is not so friendly as msconfig